Data is not getting populated in LocationStatus and ApptAssistantInfoUrl field in AssignedResource Object for mechanic tracking in FSL app
We have a requirement that customer can track mechanic's location. For that we have installed and set up Appointment Assistant package.

Created new Status value under the Service Object, known as 'Enroute' under the status category "In Progress" and added a quick action button to change the status to "Enroute" in the FSL app.
We are also assigning a resource to the SA and i'm logged in in FSL app with the User which is assigned to that Service resource.
At the time of updatiion of the status to 'Enroute',  LocationStatus and ApptAssistantInfoUrl field should get populated in Assigned Resource object. LocationStatus value should be 'EnRoute' at first.
But I could see both fields are black on that Assigned Resource record.

FYI: I have enabled the location settings on my mobile and Latitude and Longitude are being captured in related Service Resource record as Last Known Location.
Is there any extra setup I need to do to get those two fields to update?
